# Apache DocumentRoot to a Network Directory for Virtual Host

Tags: windows, apache, vhosts, document-root, network-drive

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName tmp
DocumentRoot "//192.168.1.25/www/"
<Directory />
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This configuration is not working, Services can't start from Services.msc but if i tried to run httpd.exe in cmd.exe then it successful and obviously its not good way.

I have tried Alias but still not working, services Run but when i access its `403 Access Error.`

I tried Map Network Drive to Z: but Services Fail to run from Services.msc

Do any one have good solution to Run Apache DocumentRoot from a Network Directory or Network Drive for virtual host.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is Answer http://adam-carter.com/posts/158

1. Change your DocumentRoot to the network share (drive remapping
   doesn’t seem to work).  Example: DocumentRoot “//path/to/share”
2. Make sure to update the DocumentRoot path in your  config
3. Edit the Apache service and On the “Log On’” tab, click the “Browse” button next to the “This account” radio button.
4. Type in an account name that has access privileges to the network share and click “OK”
5. Enter the correct password for the user Restart Apache and LOL your way to the bank.

Using this you can add Network Drive, Network Directory to both Virtual Host as well as in Alias.

Comment: yould you provide an example for step 1) ? I have a Network share drive U:/ and let's say a folder inside it. Path

U:/folder/

how do i access that? Apache fails to load if i change it to

//u/folder 
or something like that

Comment: U:/ is drive name and it must have some network path. like we can map a network drive to path //192.168.1.5/someDirectory so you need to put //192.168.1.5/someDirectory path in apache not drive letter